# Maximum Data Size of iMessage

Tags: macos, messages

I was wondering how big a document (picture, voice, video) can be "iMessaged" from an iPhone. Also, would the iMessage data size be any different if you are iMessaging from within Mountain Lion.

Comment: Also see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70645/is-there-a-limit-for-the-attachment-size-in-messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extracted from [Mountain Lion's Features][1] page:

> **Send large attachments:** Send high-quality photos, full HD video, or documents. iMessage allows attachments of up to **100MB**.

The max file attachment size for the iMessage and Business Chat services is 100 MB.  Platform (iOS, macOS) doesn't matter in this case.  Both channels are IP-based, not carrier-based, so it's just WiFi or cellular data.

Answer (score -2):

In my 8 1.5mb photos at once is the limit.

Comment: In your 8 what?