# Is there a limit for the attachment size in Messages?

Tags: macos, messages, attachments

I'm trying to send a **36 MB** `.mp4` video via Messages, but I'm not exactly sure if it's working.

After sending the file, the CPU usage of the processes `VTDecoderXPCService` and `IMTranscoderAgent` goes up very high (~300%) and then **only about 11 MB of data are send**.

I doubt that Messages is performing some magical compression that results in <30% of the original video file size for the transfer, instead I assume that the whole file is not send. But I'm not receiving a warning such as:
 *"Could not transfer file. Attachment too large..."*

Is there a limit for the attachment size in Messages?

Comment: Are you posting using your text messaging service or icloud?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite Joost's links, Apple did *officially* provide a size limit for Messages attachments.

Extracted from [Mountain Lion's Features](http://www.apple.com/osx/whats-new/features.html#messages) page:

> **Send large attachments:** Send high-quality photos, full HD video, or documents. iMessage allows attachments of up to **100MB**.

Your **36MB** file is well within the limit.

Comment: Great, an official source! I'm just surprised that Apple hasn't released a support document yet (http://support.apple.com/). These /osx/whats-new links on apple's homepage change with every release.

Comment: Nice find! I agree with gentmatt though - they should add these things to support.apple instead

Comment: How is ***36MB*** greater than ***100MB***?

Comment: @Thinkr – I might not have phrased that properly. That being said, I wasn't answering the question of why the video wasn't being sent, but the actual question,  of iMessage's maximum attachment size.

Comment: Yes. This probably needs some rephrasing.

Comment: @Thinkr – Done!

Comment: @Thecafremo Nice!

Answer (score 2):

It seems Apple has not documented this properly. Some articles show that [220MB is over the limit](http://www.theverge.com/2012/2/19/2809278/messages-os-x-file-transfer) and that it's most likely [between 101.4MB and 194MB](http://www.mactrast.com/2012/08/os-x-mountain-lion-all-about-messages-imessage-for-mac/)

In either case, your 36MB file should not be hitting any limits. That means there must be something else going on.

Comment: Thanks for posting information linked to empirical testing. I'll trust TheVerge, but that second source is very vague. ("...limits are reported to be somewhere...")