# How many MB can I send on iMessage?

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, data-transfer

I was wondering if anyone could tell me how many MB I can send over iMessage? And when and why messages get compressed sometimes seemingly by random. I find it very awkward that Apple made this very important information secret and nowhere to be found on the net.

iPhone 6, iOS 9.x

Comment: Check this out http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70645/is-there-a-limit-for-the-attachment-size-in-messages

Comment: Thanks! it answered it but didn't explain why some messages sometimes get compressed (that is not 100MB). I was just abroad and got a movie from home and that video should be under 100MB. And yes, iMessage was on. Odd!

Answer (score 2):

This is from the iPhone user guide:

> **Share photos, videos, your location, and more**
>  
>   With iMessage or MMS,
>   you can send and receive photos and videos, and send locations,
>   contact info, and voice memos. The size limit of attachments is
>   determined by your service provider— iPhone may compress photo and
>   video attachments when necessary.

You didn't indicate if you needed an answer for *wifi* or *cellular*.

Comment: Well an answer for each would be good. And I can't see an answer for either on the text you provided, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @MacProGirl, This a clear answer for cellular: it's up to your carrier.  Therefore, Apple doesn't put a limit on it, your cell carrier does.

Comment: That's not correct. See the other correct answer. 100 MB is the limit.