# What is the iMessage character limit?

Tags: icloud, messages

Referring to iMessages, not SMS. Pasting text ~20,800 characters long gives an error that the message is too long on my Mac. What's the limit?

Comment: TIL the attachment size limit is/was 100 MB http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59946/maximum-data-size-of-imessage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of macOS 10.12 iMessage (Messages app) seems to be able to send arbitrarily long messages without breaking them up or returning an error.

I have managed to send very large messages over 25k characters at this point. iOS then displays these in a larger message format that makes it easier to read the message when it is expanded.

Comment: I confirmed this. The above answer was correct for 10.10.5 but no longer applies to the latest iMessage which appears capable of sending very long messages.

Comment: Nice to know you could pirate a novel by iMessage.

Answer (score 6):

(This answer doesn't apply to the latest version of Messages in 10.12 which appears capable of sending VERY large messages)

TL;DR; In 10.10.5 the limit is 18996 but you can't paste in a block that large.

This isn't the answer you want but it's the answer you should listen to:

iMessage isn't designed for sending huge long messages. Write an email instead.

But if you really want an answer the max characters is 18996 but the catch is that iMessage on OSX (10.10.5) won't let you paste in a single block of text that big. Try breaking up and pasting in smaller 1000 character chunks if you must use this platform to send large amounts of text.

Comment: Well, 18,996! Thank you for the answer :) Would you happen to know why the number is so specific?

Comment: It's a weird number, I can't figure it out. I only found it by accident pasting in 1000 characters at a time and then counting once it hit the limit. I assume it's probably some max char length in whatever DB they're using.